# MariaDB: How to get a part of string

Tags: sql, mariadb, substring, varchar

How to get a part of an string from a MariaDB?

I would like to update from a table to another.But my problem is that I don't know how to  get only a part of string.
I would like to get the part before the first "/".
For example for SQL i could do:

```
select substring(lesson,1,CHARINDEX('/', lesson) -1)) from lesson
```

In MariaDB i don't find a function like charindex.

Table example:

[image]

I find INSTR function in MariaDB!
Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str. This is the same as the two-argument form of LOCATE(), except that the order of the arguments is reversed.

The solution is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(lessonr1,INSTR(flesson, '/')-1) FROM lesson ;
```

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING(lessonr1,INSTR(flesson'/')-1)
FROM lesson ;

Comment: Try using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/substring_index/)

Comment: thank you i had tried substring but is not that i want. I find the solution ....

Comment: Why not? `select substring_index(lesson, '/', 1) from lesson` returns the first part.

Comment: It'ok and work this select substring_index(lesson, '/', 1) from lesson
And also SELECT SUBSTRING(lesson,1,INSTR(lesson'/')-1) FROM lesson ;